# How to randomly select characters from string using PHP?

Tags: php, string, random, whitespace

For example I have the string,

```
$str = "abab cdcd efef"
```

How can I select two letters from each section of the string? I'm wanting to randomly generate something like this:

```
$result = "ab cc fe"
```

from the above. Is there a way to do that?

If not, can I split the string into three strings automatically? Is there a way to split a string depending on whitespace, or after a certain amount of characters (4)?
Thanks.

EDIT: Can I use explode for this?

Comment: What have you tried? http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php should be enough to get you started.

Comment: Where is your coding. What have you tried so far? What is the problem in that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is

```
$str = "abab cdcd efef";
$list = array_map(function ($v) {
    $v = str_split($v);
    shuffle($v);
    return implode(current(array_chunk($v, 2)));
}, explode(" ", $str));

echo "<pre>";
print_r($list);
```

[Output](http://eval.in/5744)

```
Array
(
    [0] => ab
    [1] => cd
    [2] => ef
)
```

[Simple Online Demo](http://eval.in/5744)

Comment: You are welcome .... Net time add some code  to show effort so that you don't get downvoted ....

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$str = "abab cdcd efef";

$values=explode(" ",$str);
$output="";
foreach($values as $value)
{
    $output.= substr($value,2)." ";
}
echo trim($output);


?>
```

Edit:  One attempt at random can be

```
$output.= substr($value,rand(0,strlen($value)-2),2)." ";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this-

```
$str = "abab cdcd efef";
$array = explode(" ",$str);
$rand_keys = array_rand($array, 1);
```

Comment: please change $input to a name used above. $input is undefined